# When clicking a row, KnockoutJS returns an empty JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

My problem is that when I click a row that is data-bound in KnockoutJS, the data that is sent to my `selectItem` function is empty and only displays `{"data":{}}` in the Firefox Web Console.

What I do not understand is how to get the values of my table cells so that I can refer to the `sender` portion of my JSON object? At the moment, it is empty.

KnockoutJS:

```
function ServiceViewModel() {
   var self = this;
   self.rows = ko.observableArray();

   $.ajax({
          method: "GET",
          url: "URL",
          success: function(data) {
             var observableData = ko.mapping.fromJSON(data);
             var array = observableData();
             self.rows(array);
          }
   });

   self.computedRows = ko.computed(function() {
       if(!self.query()) {
          return self.rows();
       } else {
          return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.rows(), function(row) {
             return row.sender() == self.query();
          });
       }
   });

   self.selectedItem = ko.observable();
   self.selectItem = function(data) {
       self.selectedItem(data);
       console.log(JSON.stringify(self.selectedItem()));
   };

};

$(document).ready(function() {
   var svc = new ServiceViewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(svc);
});
```

JSON:

```
[{"statusmsg":"OK","data":{"status":"running"},"sender":"hostname","statuscode":0}]
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Host</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: computedRows().sort(function(l, r) { return l.sender() > r.sender() ? 1 : -1})">
         <tr data-bind="click: $root.selectItem">
            <td data-bind="text: sender"></td>
            <td><span data-bind="text: data.status"></span></td>
            <td>
               <div class="btn-group">
                  <button data-bind="click: $root.selectItem">Start</button>
                  <button>Stop</button>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: BTW, is this line `var array = observableData();` working? I don't think ko.mapping returns you an observable root object, all the properties under the return object are observable, not the result object itself.

Comment: @huocp: yes, it is working. This is from a REST server that returns responses in JSON. It does not set the MIME type.

Comment: got it, thx. your data is pure array. `ko.mapping` does return an observable.

Comment: @huocp: jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jg5ux/

Comment: Just one hint. If you don't need the debug console print anymore, you can get rid of `selectItem` function. In your binding, can use `click: $root.selectedItem` directly since a ko observable object is a function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ko.toJSON to convert your knockout model to json instead of JSON.stringify as knockout uses functions for the observables.

```
console.log(ko.toJSON(self.selectedItem()));
```